# Problem with 'shrink'

Tags: errors, packages

I have a very basic problem. When I use `shrink` command I receive an error page as below.

Here is my code

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\title{ İkili Değişken ve Lojistik Regresyon}
\author[Günal]{Günal }
\institute{ Y}
\date{\today}

\setcounter{page}{51}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\titlepage

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[shrink=30]

\frametitle{Giriş}

\section{İkili Değişken Nedir?}

\textbf{İkili Değişken Nedir?}

İkili değişken sadece 2 muhtemel sonucu gösteren kesikli değişkendir. Örneğin: yazı-tura, doğum-ölüm, vb.

\begin{equation}
  Z = \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{Eğer sonuç başarı ise} \\
      0 & \text{Eğer sonuç başarısızlık ise}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(Z=1)=\pi 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(Z=0)=1- \pi 
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and here is the error

[image]

Hope that much info is enough for you to comment. I guess I need to add some particular package, but do not which one.

Comment: If I use a minimal preamble, I get no error. I don't think the problem is in `shrink=20`, because TeX stops at `\end{frame}`

Comment: But when I remove shrink, it perfectly works. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Please, add a [minimal (non) working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Please show us the code of the compkete frame, better make a compilable MWE. That shows us for example which packages you use which can be a reason for the error.

Comment: I have added the whole code. It works when [shrink=30] is ruled out. Any idea how to get this to work with [shrink=30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not specific to `shrink`. The Turkish module of `babel` activates `=` and this causes problems for the interpretation of key-value syntax.

If you have an up-to-date TeX system you can disable the `=` shorthand (that does nothing useful, in my opinion) maintaining the other two:

```
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
```

With an older TeX system (with `babel` 3.8 or older), it's a bit more obscure:

```
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`==12 }
```

Comment: Latex becomes so annoying sometimes. Thanks @egres it works now

Comment: @Günal It's your fault that Turkish is a complicated language. `;-)`